# My jupyter and ipython refer to diffrent tensorflows

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter

In Jupyter:

```
tf.__path__
_NamespacePath(['C:\\Users\\Lior\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\tensorflow'])
type(tf.__path__)
```

In ipython:

```
tf.__path__
['c:\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\api\\_v2',
 'C:\\Users\\Lior\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\tensorflow_estimator\\python\\estimator\\api\\_v2',
 'C:\\Users\\Lior\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\tensorboard\\summary\\_tf',
 'c:\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow',
 'c:\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\_api\\v2']
```

In Jupyter:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
print(np.array(dir(tf)))
```

**['**doc**' '**file**' '**loader**' '**name**' '**package**' '**path**'
'**spec**']**

In ipython:

```
import tensorflow as tf; import numpy as np; print(np.array(dir(tf)))
```

**['AggregationMethod' 'Assert' 'CriticalSection' 'DType' 'DeviceSpec'
'GradientTape' 'Graph' 'IndexedSlices' 'IndexedSlicesSpec' 'Module'
'Operation' 'OptionalSpec' 'RaggedTensor' 'RaggedTensorSpec'
'RegisterGradient' 'SparseTensor' 'SparseTensorSpec' 'Tensor'
'TensorArray' 'TensorArraySpec' 'TensorShape' 'TensorSpec' 'TypeSpec'
'UnconnectedGradients' 'Variable' 'VariableAggregation'
'VariableSynchronization' '_API_MODULE' '_LazyLoader' '**all**'
'**builtins**' '**cached**' '**compiler_version**' '**cxx11_abi_flag**'
'**doc**' '**file**' '**git_version**' '**internal**' '**loader**'
'**monolithic_build**' '**name**' '**operators**' '**package**'
'**path**' '**spec**' '**version**' '_api' '_compat'
'_current_file_location' '_current_module' '_distutils'
'_estimator_module' '_fi' '_inspect' '_keras_module' '_keras_package'
'_kernel_dir' '_ll' '_logging' '_major_api_version' '_module_dir'
'_module_util' '_names_with_underscore' '_os' '_plugin_dir'
'_running_from_pip_package' '_s' '_site' '_site_packages_dirs' '_sys'
'_tf2' '_tf_api_dir' '_tf_dir' '_typing' 'abs' 'acos' 'acosh' 'add'
'add_n' 'argmax' 'argmin' 'argsort' 'as_dtype' 'as_string' 'asin' 'asinh'
'assert_equal' 'assert_greater' 'assert_less' 'assert_rank' 'atan'
'atan2' 'atanh' 'audio' 'autodiff' 'autograph' 'batch_to_space'
'bfloat16' 'bitcast' 'bitwise' 'bool' 'boolean_mask'
'broadcast_dynamic_shape' 'broadcast_static_shape' 'broadcast_to' 'case'
'cast' 'clip_by_global_norm' 'clip_by_norm' 'clip_by_value' 'compat'
'complex' 'complex128' 'complex64' 'concat' 'cond' 'config' 'constant'
'constant_initializer' 'control_dependencies' 'convert_to_tensor' 'cos'
'cosh' 'cumsum' 'custom_gradient' 'data' 'debugging' 'device'
'distribute' 'divide' 'double' 'dtensor' 'dtypes' 'dynamic_partition'
'dynamic_stitch' 'edit_distance' 'eig' 'eigvals' 'einsum' 'ensure_shape'
'equal' 'errors' 'estimator' 'executing_eagerly' 'exp' 'expand_dims'
'experimental' 'extract_volume_patches' 'eye' 'feature_column' 'fill'
'fingerprint' 'float16' 'float32' 'float64' 'floor' 'foldl' 'foldr'
'function' 'gather' 'gather_nd' 'get_current_name_scope' 'get_logger'
'get_static_value' 'grad_pass_through' 'gradients' 'graph_util' 'greater'
'greater_equal' 'group' 'guarantee_const' 'half' 'hessians'
'histogram_fixed_width' 'histogram_fixed_width_bins' 'identity'
'identity_n' 'image' 'import_graph_def' 'init_scope' 'initializers'
'inside_function' 'int16' 'int32' 'int64' 'int8' 'io' 'is_tensor' 'keras'
'less' 'less_equal' 'linalg' 'linspace' 'lite' 'load_library'
'load_op_library' 'logical_and' 'logical_not' 'logical_or' 'lookup'
'losses' 'make_ndarray' 'make_tensor_proto' 'map_fn' 'math' 'matmul'
'matrix_square_root' 'maximum' 'meshgrid' 'metrics' 'minimum' 'mlir'
'multiply' 'name_scope' 'negative' 'nest' 'newaxis' 'nn' 'no_gradient'
'no_op' 'nondifferentiable_batch_function' 'norm' 'not_equal'
'numpy_function' 'one_hot' 'ones' 'ones_initializer' 'ones_like'
'optimizers' 'pad' 'parallel_stack' 'pow' 'print' 'profiler'
'py_function' 'qint16' 'qint32' 'qint8' 'quantization' 'queue' 'quint16'
'quint8' 'ragged' 'random' 'random_index_shuffle'
'random_normal_initializer' 'random_uniform_initializer' 'range' 'rank'
'raw_ops' 'realdiv' 'recompute_grad' 'reduce_all' 'reduce_any'
'reduce_logsumexp' 'reduce_max' 'reduce_mean' 'reduce_min' 'reduce_prod'
'reduce_sum' 'register_tensor_conversion_function' 'repeat'
'required_space_to_batch_paddings' 'reshape' 'resource' 'reverse'
'reverse_sequence' 'roll' 'round' 'saturate_cast' 'saved_model'
'scalar_mul' 'scan' 'scatter_nd' 'searchsorted' 'sequence_mask' 'sets'
'shape' 'shape_n' 'sigmoid' 'sign' 'signal' 'sin' 'sinh' 'size' 'slice'
'sort' 'space_to_batch' 'space_to_batch_nd' 'sparse' 'split' 'sqrt'
'square' 'squeeze' 'stack' 'stop_gradient' 'strided_slice' 'string'
'strings' 'subtract' 'summary' 'switch_case' 'sysconfig' 'tan' 'tanh'
'tensor_scatter_nd_add' 'tensor_scatter_nd_max' 'tensor_scatter_nd_min'
'tensor_scatter_nd_sub' 'tensor_scatter_nd_update' 'tensordot' 'test'
'tile' 'timestamp' 'tools' 'tpu' 'train' 'transpose' 'truediv'
'truncatediv' 'truncatemod' 'tuple' 'type_spec_from_value' 'types'
'uint16' 'uint32' 'uint64' 'uint8' 'unique' 'unique_with_counts'
'unravel_index' 'unstack' 'variable_creator_scope' 'variant'
'vectorized_map' 'version' 'where' 'while_loop' 'xla' 'zeros'
'zeros_initializer' 'zeros_like']**

How to make the jupyter refer to the right tf?

Comment: Not an answer because it is hard to say at first glance what _is_ the problem. However, here are three things to look into: (1) Are you using conda? If so, double-check that you using the same env. (2) Also, did you use pip to install some package that depends on tf? That is usually a source of these problems. (3) Lastly, ook into your startup scripts for ipython and Jupyter as they separate and may be doing different things.

Comment: You need to install the kernel based on the same environment in which you run ipython.

Comment: ATony, the problem is that I when I can't run the basic tf commands in Jupyter, becose there no any attributes I need. (1) How to check if I am using Conda? I have directories named conda at my computer like: conda-meta, conda_pack, conda_token ... but I dont know what sure If I using it. (2) I think yes I did pip install to many packeges.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem:

```
import sys
right_path = "c:\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages"
if sys.path[0] != right_path:
    sys.path.insert(0,right_path)
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.constant(6))
```